# Creating A Centered Footer Using Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to learn `Bootstrap` in particular `Bootstrap 4` but struggling with my footer.

It has 2 rows and i want the entire thing centered but struggling.

Below is my HTML i currently have

```
<section class="block-follow-us">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-4 col-md-1 px-0">
                <span class="h5">Follow us:</span>
            </div>
            <div class="offset-1 col-10 offset-md-0 col-md-3 px-0">
                <a href="https://twitter.com/ApolloSciUK?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor" target="_blank" class="fab fa-twitter-square"></a>
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/apollo-scientific-ltd" target="_blank" class="fab fa-linkedin"></a>
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/apolloscientific/?hl=en" target="_blank" class="fab fa-instagram"></a>
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Apollo-Scientific-Ltd/158179738244405?rf=174620749220860" target="_blank" class="fab fa-facebook-square"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-12">© 2019 - Apollo Scientific Ltd</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center text-center">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
                <a href="/">Terms and conditions</a>
            </div>                        
            <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
                <a href="/">Privacy policy</a>
            </div>                        
            <div class="col-12 col-md-1">
                <a href="/">Careers</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>        
</footer>
```

Which turns out looking like the below on desktop but all parts over the place and i have been trying for hours to sort it

[image]

And mobile looks likes fine though

[image]

Comment: Code cannot be written from mobile version of stackoverflow. I'm sorry.

Comment: @DogukanCavus - No idea what your meaning. Hope it wasn't you that down voted the post at it is a valid help question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<section class="block-follow-us">
 <div class="container">
   <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
     <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 text-center">
      <span class="h5">Follow us:</span>
       <a href="https://twitter.com/ApolloSciUK?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor" target="_blank" class="fab fa-twitter-square">Link1</a>
       <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/apollo-scientific-ltd" target="_blank" class="fab fa-linkedin">Link2</a>
       <a href="https://www.instagram.com/apolloscientific/?hl=en" target="_blank" class="fab fa-instagram">Link3</a>
       <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Apollo-Scientific-Ltd/158179738244405?rf=174620749220860" target="_blank" class="fab fa-facebook-square">Link4</a>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</section>

<footer class="footer">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row text-center">
   <div class="col-lg-12">© 2019 - Apollo Scientific Ltd</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row justify-content-center text-center">
   <div class="col-lg-4">
    <a href="/">Terms and conditions</a>
   </div>                        
   <div class="col-lg-4">
    <a href="/">Privacy policy</a>
   </div>                        
   <div class="col-lg-4">
    <a href="/">Careers</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>        
</footer>
```